# how to read in a texture picture into opengl

Tags: opengl, graphics, textures

What is the easiest format to read a texture into opengl? Are there any tutorials -good tutorials, for loading image formats like jpg, png, or raw into an array which can be used for texture mapping (preferably without the use of a library like libpng)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a handy OpenGL texture tutorial available at the link: http://www.nullterminator.net/gltexture.html

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL itself does not knows nothing about common image formats (other than natively supported S3TC/DXT compressed and alikes, but they are a different story). You need to expand you source images into RGBA arrays. Number of formats and combinations are supported. You need to choose one that suits you, e.g. GL_ALPHA4 for masks, GL_RGB5_A1 for 1bit transparency, GL_BGRA/GL_RGBA for fullcolor, etc.

For me the easiest (not the fastest) way are PNGs, for their lossless compression and full Alpha support. I read the PNG and write RGBA values into array which I then hand over to OpenGL texture creation. If you don't need alpha you may as well accept JPG or BMP. Pipeline is common Source -> Expanded RGBA array -> OpenGL texture.